# What could be causing the net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE error when attempting to POST a file to Firebase Storag?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

What could be causing the net::ERR_INVALID_HANDLE error when attempting to POST a file to Firebase Storage in connection.ts at line 81 with the specified file name and timestamp in the URL parameters?

Comment: Did you further research this? Any clue what might have caused this?

Comment: For me it was a Firebase Configuration problem, but i'm not sure if that will be the case for you.